# How to make function in a class remove word multiple times per line

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

The code below is supposed to clean out the word frack, and potentially a list of bad words. But for now the issue is with the function `clean_line`. If text line has frack more than twice, it only take the first one, also it does not react on capital letters.

```
class Cleaner:
    def __init__(self, forbidden_word = "frack"):
        """ Set the forbidden word """
        self.word = forbidden_word



    def clean_line(self, line):
        """Clean up a single string, replacing the forbidden word by *beep!*"""
        found = line.find(self.word)
        if found != -1:
            return line[:found] + "*beep!*" + line[found+len(self.word):]
        return line

    def clean(self, text):
        for i in range(len(text)):
            text[i] = self.clean_line(text[i])


example_text = [
        "What the frack! I am not going",
        "to honour that question with a response.",
        "In fact, I think you should",
        "get the fracking frack out of here!",
        "Frack you!"
        ]

clean_text = Cleaner().clean(example_text)

for line in example_text: print(line)
```

Comment: Yes, because `str.find` only gives the first index, and doesn't match case insensitively. It's also unclear what you'd expect for compound words like *"fracking"*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you just want to get rid of any word with `frack` in it, you could do something like the code below. If you need to also get rid of trailing whitespace, then you will need to change the regular expression a little bit. If you need to learn more about regular expressions, I would recommend checking out [regexone.com](https://regexone.com/).

```
# Using regular expressions makes string manipulation easier
import re

example_text = [
    "What the frack! I am not going",
    "to honour that question with a response.",
    "In fact, I think you should",
    "get the fracking frack out of here!",
    "Frack you!"
]

# The pattern below gets rid of all words which start with 'frack'
filter = re.compile(r'frack\w*', re.IGNORECASE)

# We then apply this filter to each element in the example_text list
clean = [filter.sub("", e) for e in example_text]
print(clean)
```

#### Output

```
['What the ! I am not going', 
 'to honour that question with a response.', 
 'In fact, I think you should', 
 'get the   out of here!', 
 ' you!']
```

Comment: i think if you just modify your implementation to 'censor' the word (instead of replacing it), your solution could work.

Comment: What do you mean? The code above is getting rid of all of the instances of the word. Would 'censoring' get rid of trailing whitespaces?

Comment: i mean his implementation doesn't simply strip out the bad words, it replaces them with "*beep!*"

Comment: Yeah. He didn’t ask for that in his question though, so I just left it out. But you’re right.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code to clean up your line from a bad word:

```
line = "frack one Frack two"
bad_word = "frack"    

line = line.lower()

if bad_word in line:
    clean_line = line.replace(bad_word, "")
```

Resulting in `clean_line` being:

```
"one two"
```

Comment: One note is that if you want to get rid of "fracking" then this will leave "ing".